# why parameterized queries typically execute much faster than a literal SQL string?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

my textbook says:

**"parameterized queries typically execute much faster than a literal SQL string
because they are parsed exactly once (rather than each time the SQL string is assigned to the CommandText property)."**

I'm confused, let's say we have a insert method

```
public void InsertAuto(Car car)
{
 OpenConnection();
 // Format and execute SQL statement.
 string sql = "Insert Into Inventory (Make, Color, PetName) Values " +
 $"('{car.Make}', '{car.Color}', '{car.PetName}')";
 // Execute using our connection.
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, _sqlConnection))
 {
 command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 CloseConnection();
}
```

isn't that the the sql string literal gets constructed once and straightforward?

if you do it in this way:

```
public void InsertAuto(Car car)
{
    OpenConnection();
    // Format and execute SQL statement.
    string sql = "Insert Into Inventory" + "(Make, Color, PetName) Values" + "(@Make, @Color, @PetName)";            // Execute using our connection.
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, _sqlConnection))
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Make",
            Value = car.Make,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char,
            Size = 10
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        parameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Color",
            Value = car.Color,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char,
            Size = 10
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        parameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@PetName",
            Value = car.PetName,
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char,
            Size = 10
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    CloseConnection();
}
```

somewhere it still need to swap all @variable with string value anyway?

Comment: @CaldeiraG this has nothing to do with SQL injection

Comment: Sql server will compile query and create query plans based on raw sql query text. If exactly same sql query text already compiled server will use compiled plan. Without parameters every time you change values new query text will be created and recompiled again. With parameters raw query text remain same and sql server will reuse already compiled query plan

Comment: The textbook's explanation is clear. The query is parsed just once, producing an execution plan (indexes to use, operators, join types, aggregations etc). That execution plan is reused the next time the same query gets executed with different parameters. Databases don't execute the SQL query, they treat it as source code which they compile to an execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Because parameterized queries are Belong to sql...on the other Hand  literal SQL string 
needs  time for compiling, parsing, syntax checking,etc...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.